# What is the Ruby way to determine if an array has only unique entries?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to find out if an `Array` contains only unique (distinct) entries.

```
[1,2,3,2].what_goes_here? #=> false
[1,2,3,4].what_goes_here? #=> true
```

I don't want to manipulate the original array, so

> uniq! { |item| ... } → ary or nil
>   ...
>   Returns nil if no changes are made (that is, no duplicates are found).

seems not the right solution. Otherwise I could probably do `[1,2,3,4].uniq!.nil?`.

I prefer an elegant, readable, over a convoluted-but-better-performing solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.uniq.size == array.size
array.to_set.size == array.size
array.all? { |element| array.count(element) == 1 }
```

Comment: I know I said "I prefer an elegant, readable, over a convoluted-but-better-performing solution." but your first example, while readable, seems to at least copy a uniq version as new array. Which looks very inefficient. Not?

Comment: @berkes, more inefficient that it has to be - yes. Very inefficient - depends on your use case.

Comment: You are comparing size. Is that more efficient than simply comparing arrays? In other words: what benefit gives `array.uniq.size == array.size` over `array.uniq == array`

Comment: @berkes, `==` will short circuit if the array does contain duplicating elements. If it does not however, each element from the first array will be compared to each of the second, even though you know for a fact that if the size is the same, the arrays are the same (in this case). It's a good point though, if you don't care for that, omitting `size` makes it even more concise.

Comment: @berkes, asymptotically speaking, the first two are `O(n)` time and space, the last one is `O(n^2)` time (maybe better with amortized analysis) and `O(1)` space. Optimal would be `O(n)` time, `O(1)` space.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2]

a.dup.uniq!.nil?    # false
a.uniq == a         # false
a & a == a          # false
a | a == a          # false
```

Comment: The first is quite cute!

Answer (score 1):

If the array is large you may want to use a method that examines elements sequentially and stops when a dup is found, rather than traversing the entire array. You can do that efficiently with a hash:

```
def dups?(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |e,h|
    return true if h[e]
    h[e] = true
  end
  false
end

dups? [1,2,3,1,4,5,6,3,1,8,9]
  #=> true
dups? [1,2,3,4,5,6,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1]
  #=> false
```

...or with a set:

```
require 'set'

def dups?(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Set.new) do |e,s|
    return true if s.include? e
    s << e
  end
  false
end
```